# How to get multi links and follow these links in Phantomjs?

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm beginner at Phantomjs so many problems i can't solve them myselft. Would you mind helping me to solve this problem? I have problem about getting multi dynamic urls by Phantomjs.

Example:

-- My index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Homepage</h1>
<ul>
    <li><a href="laptop.html">Laptop</a></li>
    <li><a href="tablet.html">Tablet</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

-- My laptop.html file (tablet.html file as the same) is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Laptop Page</h1>
<div class="productRow">Product of Laptop 1</div>
<div class="productRow">Product of Laptop 2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to print like this:

```
Category Name: Laptop
Product: Product of Laptop 1
Product: Product of Laptop 2
....

Category Name: Tablet
Product: Product of Tablet 1
Product: Product of Tablet 2
...
```

It's mean that i want to get content of this url http://abc.com/test/. Then i will get links of ( UL LI A HREF). And then i will follow those links to get content their sub page automatically.

This is my sample code by Phantomjs:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url  = 'http://localhost/test';

page.open(url, function() {
    //Get parent link
    var parent = page.evaluate(function() {
        var test = document.querySelectorAll('li a');
        return Array.prototype.map.call(test, function(elem) {
            return elem.href;       
        });
    });
    for(var i=0; i < parent.length; i++){
        //Print parent link 
        console.log("Parent link:" + parent[i]);

        //Then open child link          
        page.open(parent[i],function(){         
            //console.log(document.title);          
            var child = page.evaluate(function() {
                var test = document.querySelectorAll('div.productRow');
                return Array.prototype.map.call(test, function(elem) {
                    return elem.innerHTML;      
                });
            }); 
            console.log(child.length);
            phantom.exit();
        });

    }

});
```

Why's console.log(child.length) = 0? Can you help me? Thanks for your help.

Comment: where's your python code?

Answer (score 0):

Try it just like this, it should work. Of course I am assuming, that the `parent` array is properly filled with correct links.

```
var child = page.evaluate(function() {
    return [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.productRow'), function(div) {
        return div.innerHTML;
    });
});
```